# jQuery several select elements from JSON data detect change

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an ajax query which pulls some JSON data and generates me a row for each user with several select elements using `.append()` this works great. An example of one of the selects it generates is below:

```
    <select name="mailBox" id="mailBox1" class="mailbox">
      <option value="25">25 GB</option>
      <option value="50" selected="selected">50 GB</option>
      <option value="75">75 GB</option>
      <option value="100">100 GB</option>
      <option value="0">No Mail Box</option>
    </select>
```

What I would like to do is when the user changes the selected value I would like to then do an ajax post to update the database, however I am having trouble detecting the change request

I have tried this:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function(){
        // I have just stuck an alert in to show me if it has detected the change
    alert('hello');
    });
});
```

I have also tried using `$('.mailbox')` and also referencing the id directly `$('#mailBox1')` and can't detect any change. Code works fine if the select boxes are static html.

EDIT* Full jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
      var csrf = $('[name="csrf_test_name"]').val();
       $.ajax({                                      
              url: '/index.php/ajax/getCompanyUsers', data: {csrf_test_name: csrf}, dataType: 'json',  success: function(data)        
              {
                for (var i in data)
                {

                    var email = data[i].email;
                    var files = data[i].file;
            
                    var emailForm = '<select name="mailBox" id="mailBox' + paramID + '" class="mailbox"><option value="25">25 GB</option><option value="50">50 GB</option><option value="75">75 GB</option><option value="100">100 GB</option><option value="0">No Mail Box</option></select>  ';
                    var filesForm = '<select name="fileStorage" id="fileStorage' + paramID + '" class="filestorage"><option value="25">25 GB</option><option value="50">50 GB</option><option value="75">75 GB</option><option value="100">100 GB</option><option value="0">No File Storage</option></select>';
                      
                  $('#wrapper').append('<div class="company-users-email">' + emailForm + '</div>' + '<div class="company-users-filestorage">' + filesForm + '</div>');
                                                            
                 $("#mailBox" + paramID + " option[value='" + email + "']").attr("selected","selected");
                 $("#fileStorage" + paramID + " option[value='" + files + "']").attr("selected","selected");
                                
                } 
              } 
            });
            
          $('.mailbox').bind("change", function(e){ alert("hello") });      
});
```

Comment: your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/wroniasty/A2YsU/10/

Comment: having posted alternative code @wroniasty is right.  Your code is fine.

Comment: What is probably happening is that you are binding your change event event before the ajax population takes place.  try adding your events after the select population.

Comment: Hmm code works fine when i try and replicate like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wPqGq/2/ however on the page with the live data still doesn't work actually I will attach my full javascript including the ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mailBox1').bind("change", function(e){ alert("hello") });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ej8Aa/

Comment: Works brilliantly for static code, but still can't seem to get a response with the ajax generated selects

Comment: @user1606612 Its like I said above your probably trying to bind to the select before it exists in the dom.  Dont try and bind to the select till you have the ajax response and have populated the DOM.  That should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, all working now, i moved the applyBindings(); to after the for loop in the ajax function now works perfectly

Comment: @user1606612 anytime.  You should mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem :)